# Augment DataFrame index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a series (`'b'`) of a dataframe from one dataframe (df2) to another one (df1). Both DataFrames use the same index column, but the range of `df2`'s index goes a bit further and it's missing some of the indices of `df1`.

This is the current behaviour:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
>>> df1 = df.set_index(['a'])
>>> df1
   b
a   
1  4
2  5
3  6
>>> dg = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 4, 5], 'b': [7, 8, 9]})
>>> dg
   a  b
0  3  7
1  4  8
2  5  9
>>> df2 = dg.set_index('a')
>>> df2
   b
a   
3  7
4  8
5  9
>>> df1['b'] = df2['b']
>>> df1
     b
a     
1  NaN
2  NaN
3  7.0
```

When I call `df1['b'] = df2['b']` those values of the indices not in `df2` are becoming `nan` and the indices of `df2` that aren't in `df1` are not getting carried over into `df1`.

Is there any way to change this behaviour so that the resulting DataFrame is the below?

```
>>> df1
     b
a     
1  1
2  2
3  7
4  8
5  9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a use case for [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html). It will prioritize the calling dataframe and fill in any missing values with the second. It will also concatenate rows from the second data frame that don't have labels in the first.

```
df2.combine_first(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option you can go with is `reindex()` df2 and then fill missing values with df1:

```
df2 = df2.reindex(df1.index.union(df2.index))    
df2['b'] = df2['b'].fillna(df1['b'])

df2
#     b
#a  
#1  4.0
#2  5.0
#3  7.0
#4  8.0
#5  9.0
```